# What is the correct helo for a smtp server that does not receive mail and does not have a FQDN?

Tags: postfix, smtp

What is the legal and correct `helo` for my SMTP server.

- Out going email only.
- Behind a NAT with no inbound ports open.
- SMTP server does not have a FQDN.
- Send mail for 2 different domains

We are a small business that has multiple locations. We have 2 different web sites with email addresses eg.:

- product1.com : sales@product1.com
- otherproduct.biz : sales@otherproduct.biz

Our SMTP server will send email for both domains.

#### RFC2821 section 4.1.1.1

> ... and no reverse mapping record is available), the client SHOULD
>   send an address literal (see section 4.1.3), optionally followed by
>   information that will help to identify the client system.

#### 4.1.3 Address Literals**

> ... To bypass this barrier a special literal form of the address is
>   allowed as an alternative to a domain name.  For IPv4 addresses, this
>   form uses four small decimal integers separated by dots and enclosed
>   by brackets such as [123.255.37.2] ...

therefore I think that my `helo` name should be:

```
[1.2.3.4] company name INC city, state
```

#### postfix configuration

```
smtp_helo_name = [1.2.3.4] company name INC city, state
```

Using this I still get the following errors:

```
... status=bounced (host mx1c38.carrierzone.com[66.175.58.41] refused to talk to me: 501 5.0.0 Invalid domain name

... status=bounced (host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.38] refused to talk to me: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

... status=bounced (host kakllc.com[67.214.161.202] said: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

and other similar errors all pertaining to the `helo`.

Is this a correct `helo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the host a FQDN, e.g. `foo.product1.com`. Set the `HELO` to be this fully qualified domain name. Ensure that external DNS can resolve that name. Otherwise, you'll see lots of rejects, as observed, as blocking such (possibly via something like `smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname reject_non_fqdn_hostname`) is an inexpensive way to eliminate a certain percentage of incoming spam.

Comment: It may be worth adding that it's often a good idea to also set the hostname in reverse DNS (if possible), as many people also use the `reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname` restriction.  So yes, a FQDN is the way to go.

Comment: The reverse DNS lookup record (DNS PTR) for my ip-address is what I used for my server FQDN in the helo.This has stopped the rejects due to invalid helo.
My next step is to add a SPF entry to the DNS TXT record to the domains that I send email for.Please see my next question.
[SPF DNS TXT syntax](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247949/is-this-the-correct-spf-dns-txt-syntax-to-allow-the-existing-email-servers-dns)

Answer (score 1):

Using postfix (on Ubuntu 16.04.3), I was receiving the access denied message in the postfix log at /var/log/mail.log:

> 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) (in reply
>   to MAIL FROM command)

To try to get it working I added an FQDN entry for my host in /etc/hosts and changed the hostname. That alone did not work - by **commenting out** the following line to the postfix configuration at `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I was able to get it working:

```
#myhostname = ubuntu
```

You can read the default behavior for the `myhostname` setting in the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname).

To restart postfix after I made the configuration change, I used the following command:

```
sudo service postfix restart
```